# Meaning of Fokker-Planck with non-differentiable and/or infinite potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics, differential-equations, diffusion, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The Fokker-Planck equation for a diffusing particle in the potential $V$ is
$$\partial_t p  = -\nabla\cdot (p \nabla V)  + D \Delta p.\tag{1}$$
In the literature, one often sees this formulation used with non-differentiable and infinite-valued potentials, in particular the "infinite square well" potential $$V(x)=\begin{cases} 0& \text{if $x\in[0,1]$}\\ \infty&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
What is the best way to interpret the PDE in $(1)$ given such a potential? I'm imagining one can treat it as  a limit of differentiable/finite potentials, but perhaps there are other approaches?

Any good references would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These have to be treated as *zero-flux boundary conditions*: the particles cannot leave the region $[0,1]$. Note that this is different from the *absorbing boundary conditions*, where the probability is zero at the boundary points. Unlike in quantum mechanics, absorbing boundary conditions in real diffusion equation mean that the normalization is not conserved (the particle escapes through sinks).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That makes sense that having zero-flux boundary conditions is the correct way to formalize impenetrable walls. However, I have seen potentials like the infinite square well used in the literature, and I'm wondering how to interpret them. For example, is there a formal way to show that those potentials are, in some sense, "equivalent" to zero-flux boundary conditions?